# Netbeans jTable custom WHERE clause

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, where-clause

Something simple I guess... I have a jTable created by Netbeans, which is bound to a mysql DB.

The table is getting all the data from the table, but I only need to get data with a particular field value. Netbeans creates a class automatically, but I can't find a place to add a WHERE clause.

For example I need the table to execute the final query as, SELECT * WHERE ID = 123;

Comment: "SELECT * WHERE ID = 123" is  a wrong mysql query...Post SSCCE and go through this documentation, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the FAQ about how to post questions and what questions to ask here. We expect that you do research before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * where ID = 123
```

is incorrect as a query. You should research first, in 30 seconds I've found [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/238459-how-to-fill-jtable-using-sql-select-statement/), which I believe solves the problem.

Comment: I know its not the correct syntax, I missed the FROM table part, but it was just an example that I only need to edit the WHERE clause. unfortunately from the link you gave me I wasn't able to solve my issue.
My jTable was created by Netbeans IDE, drag and drop, so the code was automatically generated. So my question is how can I edit the code generated by netbeans. The table is being populated by all the data in the database table, but I only want to get data with a particular ID.